# Make custom view focusable in tvOS using .focused( :equals) in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, focus, tvos

I have a very simple custom view which only consists of a RoundedRectangle:

```
public struct SimpleView: View {

    @State public var focused = false

    public var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .fill(.green)
            .scaleEffect( focused ? 1.0 : 0.8 )
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: focused)
    }
}
```

I have to instances of this `SimpleView` in a container view:

public enum EnumView: Hashable {
case one
case two
case three
}

```
public struct GalleryView: View {

    var s1 = SimpleView()
    var s2 = SimpleView()
    var s3 = SimpleView()

    @FocusState var fokus: EnumView?

    public init() {

    }

    public var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            s1.focused($fokus, equals: .one)
                .onChange(of: fokus) { newFocusedField in
                    log.info("| New focus \(newFocusedField)")

                }
            s2.focused($fokus, equals: .two)
                .onChange(of: fokus) { newFocusedField in
                    log.info("| New focus \(newFocusedField)")

                }

            s3.focused($fokus, equals: .three)
                .onChange(of: fokus) { newFocusedField in
                    log.info("| New focus \(newFocusedField)")

                }
        }

    }
}
```

Before I've used the "`focusable(true)`" - Modifier in the `SimpleView` which allowed me to move the focus between the three child views which expanded or shrinked depending where the focus was.

According to Apple the "`focusable(true)`" - Modifier is **deprecated** so I wanted to replace this solution with the new `"focused(... , equals: )"` - Modifier.

But still after over two days of trying I don't get it to work. It works when I used Buttons for example but not my custom view.

Basically I want to move the focus horizontally and the views should expand or shrink depending on their current focus state.

Any ideas who to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: It isn’t possible right now.

Comment: But it worked using ".focusable(true)".onChange { ... } and it works using Button etc. - so what do I have to implement in my custom view which is implemented in a e.g. a Button?

Comment: I managed to get the desired effect by wrapping the rounded rectangle etc. as a label in a Button. 

But I still don't know why the "focusable" - Modifier works and the ".focused" - Modifier not.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by using the rounded rectangle as the label of a button. So this works now:

```
public struct SimpleView: View {

    public var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Button( action: {} ,
                        label: {
                    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.5)
                            .fill(.green)
                }
                ).buttonStyle(.card)
            }
        }
    }
}
```